# Is H.L. Royden's REAL ANALYSIS, 4th edition, suitable for these two introductory functional analysis courses?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, education, book-recommendation

Is the book *Real Analysis* by H.L. Royden, 4th edition, suitable for two introductory functional analysis courses comprising the following topics?

**First Course:**

Metric spaces: A quick review, convergence and completeness, completion

Normed Spaces: Linear spaces, normed spaces, relation between normed and metric spaces, Banach spaces, bounded and continuous linear operators and functionals, dual spaces, finite-dimensional normed spaces, F. Riesz lemma, the Hahn-Banach (HB) theorems (for real and complex vector spaces and for normed spaces), the open-mapping theorem,  the closed-graph theorem, the uniform boundedness principle and its applications

The Banach fixed-point theorem with applications to algebraic, differential, and integral equations

**Second Course:**

Hilbert Spaces: Inner product space & Hilbert space, orthogonal & orthonormal sets, orthogonal complements, Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process, the Riesz representation theorem for representation of functionals on a Hilbert spaces in terms of the inner product, weak and weak* convergence

Finite-Dimensional Spectral Theory: The definition of spectrum of an operator and some examples, spectral properties of self-adjoint operators, the spectral-mapping theorem for finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces

Can Royden be used to learn the above topics or teach those topics to a group of students who are not very sharp and whose mathematical maturity isn't very good?

How about Royden being used together with the book *Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications* by Erwine Kreyszig?

The issue with Kreyszig is that

(1) it doesn't take measure theory into consideration at all,

(2) it is not rigorous enough in some of its proofs,

and

(3) it is unnecessarily wordy at some other places

Maybe a second edition of Kreyszig will take care of these issues.

But is it a good idea to use Royden as a textbook for both the Functional Analysis (I & II) courses (consisting of the above-mentioned topics) as well as for the Measure Theory (I & II) courses learnt by or taught to the same audience?

Last but not least, links please to web pages of courses taught using either or both of the above two books, especially the former!

Comment: Kreyszig died in 2008, so I wouldn't expect a second edition.

Comment: I'm curious, do you have an example in mind for where Kreyszig is "not rigorous enough"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I think the proof of the converse part of Theorem 2.7-9 (a), where he is content with using the $\leq$, whereas the definitions he gives using the $<$ strict inequalities. Of course, one can show that definitions of convergence and continuity given using $<$ are equivalent to the corresponding definitions given using $\leq$, but the author of an introductory-level textbook should explicitly demonstrate this fact, or else just give proofs using the $<$ inequalities as given in the definitions.

Comment: If it's anything like the second or third edition, I would not recommend Royden's book for a functional analysis course: its goal is to introduce measure-theoretic topisc through real analysis, but if you compare it to, say, Brézis' *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations*, there is hardly anything of of functional analysis.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom another example where Kreyszig lacks in rigor is in Definition 3.1-1, where the author begins by assuming $X$ to be a vecotr space over an arbitrary scalar field $K$ but in the (IP3) of the definition he uses the fact that the field of scalars is the field $\mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood Okay, thanks for that